# cdec installation

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, cmake

Could you please let me know, how can I install cdec on Ubuntu 14.04?
Because the new type of cdec installation (CMake) doesn't work on my system!
Does any one know that, is there any step by step tutorial for installing the new version of cdec platform on Ubuntu 14.04?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about a link to the download and steps you used

Comment: This is the link which I am following:           http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mdenkows/cdec-realtime.html

Comment: Thats a long tutorial which part did you fail on ?

Comment: Download and build the cdec toolkit:                                                                  cd ~/prefix/sw
git clone https://github.com/redpony/cdec.git
cd cdec
autoreconf -ifv
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX
make

Comment: and Build the Python interface to cdec:                                                                             cd ~/prefix/sw/cdec/python
python setup.py build_ext --inplace

Comment: On the first one error is `bash: cd: /home/username/prefix/sw: No such file or directory` ?

Comment: No! the error is autoconf ac, or autoconf in is required

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` then
`sudo apt-get install autoconf`

Comment: Sorry! The error message is : 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required

Comment: What is the exact line that gives this error, `autoreconf -ifv` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instructions for building the software using `cmake` are provided in the `BUILDING` file that is distributed with the source code i.e.

```
Instructions for building
-----------------------------------

 1) Create a build directory and generate Makefiles using CMake

        mkdir build
        cd build
        cmake ..

    If the cmake command completes successfully, you can proceed. If you have
    libraries (such as Boost) installed in nonstandard locations, you may need
    to run cmake with special options like -DBOOST_ROOT=/path/to/boost.

 2) Build

        make -j 2

 3) Test
        make test
        ./tests/run-system-tests.pl

    Everything should pass.

 4) Enjoy!
```

However, it seems that the perl script in step 3) actually assumes that the build was done 'in tree' rather than 'out of tree' i.e. by running `cmake .` followed by `make` in the *parent* `cdec` directory, instead of using a separate `build` subdirectory.

If you have followed the suggested steps 1) and 2) above, then probably the simplest way to run the tests is to copy the `cdec/test` directory into your `build` directory e.g. from inside `build`, execute

```
cp -r ../tests/ ./
```

You should then be able to run `./tests/run-system-tests.pl` also from within the `build` directory.

Alternatively, you could start over and do an in-tree build instead.

Comment: bash: ./tests/run-system-tests.pl: No such file or directory

Comment: @user297091 so it seems that the instructions for running the tests actually assume that you have done an in-tree build i.e. run `cmake .` and then `make` from the top-level `cdec` directory instead of running `cmake ..` from within a separate `build` subdirectory. You should bring this to the attention of the package's maintainers.